# In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle A=60^\circ$ and $\angle B=30^\circ$ and $AD$ the bisector of $\angle A=60^\circ$. Find $\frac{AD}{BC}=?$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$ we have:
$$\angle A=60^\circ$$
$$\angle B=30^\circ$$
And bisector of the angle $\angle A=60^\circ$ is $AD$ that divides it into 2 equal parts:
$$\angle CAD=30^\circ$$
$$\angle DAB=30^\circ$$
So we want now find:
$$\frac{AD}{BC}=?$$
I have written all trigonometric relations between the sides. But unhopefully no results. Would you hint me about these relations?

Comment: Yeah but everyone knows them!

Comment: Have you included all the trigonometric relations between the sides in you post?  I don't see those.  I see info about angles,  only.  Please do not leave out work you've done that might prove crucial to solving the question.  We know, by deduction, that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, given $|\angle A| + |\angle B| = 90^\circ$.  That is, $\angle C = 180^\circ - 90^\circ = 90^\circ$.  Please include more of the work you did, as an edit to your post.

Comment: At first you must compute the length of $$AD$$ by the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: So can you have a complete answer!?

Comment: Look @amWhy I know that Sin60=cos30 and also cos30=CD/AD But i am sorry. You actually must know that as a high school student that has an exam tomorrow I can not write everything here! Actually i liked to but the time is so limited

Comment: Sorry, but my time is limited too.  I don't necessarily cater to users who ask *urgent questions* for homework due the next day, or have an exam on Sunday?.  Please don't ask more of answerers than you're willing to do in a question.  Please read the helpful thread: [How to ask a good question on math.se, (if you want a good answer)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  I'll have to go know.

Comment: PS: all users who answer questions do so *voluntarily*.  All users who interact with askers, do so *voluntarily*.  No one on this site, not even the site moderators, are here doing this for a living.  Every second of anyone's time here given to help others is given voluntarily; no one here gets paid a dime.

Comment: So ok. Im really sorry. I didnt know that

Answer (score 2):

Since $AC:AB=1:2$ we know that $D$ as bisector divides $CB$in the same relation, so $D$ divides $CB$ in relation $1:2$. From
$\angle(DAC)=\angle(ABD)=30^{\circ}$
we conclude $AD=BD$ and finally we have we have $AD:BC=BD:BC=2:3$.

Yet another solution: reflect the triangle on $BC$ to get an equilateral triangle $ABA’$; the prolongation of $AD$ meets $A’B$ in $D’$.  Now $AD’$ and $BC$ are also  medians with the same length and their intersection $D$ divides each in relation $1:2$ again.

Comment: Typographical error:  You meant to write $D$ as bisector divides $CB$ in the same relation.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you wrote all trigonometric relations between the sides. Now you should relate them to each other. There are so many relations one can find.

Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

**Method $1$:** (Michael Hoppe): Note that the triangle $ABD$ is isosceles, hence $AD=BD$.

Note that $\sin 30^\circ=\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac12$. From the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) we find: $$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{CD}{BD} \Rightarrow CD=0.5BD \Rightarrow \frac{AD}{BC}=\frac{BD}{BD+0.5BD}=\frac23.$$

**Method $2$** (Michael Rozenberg): Note that the triangle $ABD$ is isosceles, hence $AD=BD$.

Note that $\sin 30^\circ=\frac{CD}{AD}=\frac12 \Rightarrow CD=0.5AD$. Thus: $\frac{AD}{BC}=\frac{AD}{CD+BD}=\frac{AD}{0.5AD+AD}=\frac23$.

**Method $3$:** Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{5cm}$ [image]

Note that the triangle $ABD$ is isosceles, hence $AD=BD$.

Also, note that the triangles $ACD, ADE, BDE$ are congruent.

Let $S$ be the area of $ABC$. Then:
$$\frac12\cdot AD\cdot AC\cdot \sin 30^\circ = \frac S3 \Rightarrow AD\cdot AC=\frac{4S}3;\\
\frac12\cdot BC\cdot \underbrace{AB}_{2AC}\cdot \sin 30^\circ = S \Rightarrow BC\cdot AC=2S;\\
\frac{AD}{BC}=\frac23.$$

**Method $4$:** Use the angle bisector formula $l_a^2=\frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}\cdot [(b+c)^2-a^2]$:
$$\begin{align}AD^2&=\frac{AC\cdot AB}{(AC+AB)^2}\cdot [(AC+AB)^2-BC^2]=\\
&=\frac{AC\cdot 2AC}{(AC+2AC)^2}\cdot [(AC+2AC)^2-BC^2]=\\
&=\frac{2}{9}\cdot [(3\cdot \frac{BC}{\sqrt{3}})^2-BC^2]=\\
&=\frac{4}{9}BC^2 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{AD}{BC}&=\frac23.\end{align}$$
Good luck on your studies!

**Addendum.**

**Method $5$ (thinking out of box):** (Michael Hoppe): Reflect the triangle on $BC$ as shown on the figure below.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Note that $BC$ and $AD'$ are both medians and at the intersection point $D$ they are divided in the ratio $1:2$, that is, $CD:BD=1:2$, which implies $AD:BC=BD:BC=2:3$.

**Method $6$ (thinking out of box):** Extend the side $BC$ such that $CD=CD'$ as shown on the figure below:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Note that the triangle $ADD'$ is equilateral triangle. Hence, $AD=DD'$, which are the radii of the circumscribed circle, implying $DD'=BD$. Hence, $AD:BC=BD:BC=2:3$.

Comment: There is yet another solution, which requires no calculation at all; see my edit, please.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, elegant solution of yours, indeed and challenge is accepted.

Comment: Method 6 is cute as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$\measuredangle C=180^{\circ}-30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=90^{\circ}.$$
$\measuredangle B=\measuredangle DAB=30^{\circ},$ which gives $BD=AD.$

Also, since $\measuredangle DAC=30^{\circ},$ we obtain $DC=\frac{1}{2}AD.$

Id est, $$\frac{AD}{BC}=\frac{AD}{BD+DC}=\frac{AD}{AD+\frac{1}{2}AD}=\frac{2}{3}.$$